# Average of Data in accordance with similar time

Tags: r, time, dataset, rscript

I have a  dataset having solar power generation for 24 hours for many days, now I have to find the average of the power generated in accordance with the time, as for example, [Have a glimpse of the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDhAb.png)I have to find the average of the power generated at time 9:00:00 AM.

Comment: Please post data as plain text, not images, so users can copy/paste it.

Comment: Okay, from next time i will take care

Answer (score 0):

Start by stripping out the time from the date-time variable.

Assuming your data is called myData

```
library(lubridate)

myData$Hour <- hour(strptime(myData$Time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

Then use `ddply` from the `plyr` package, which allows us to apply a function to a subset of data.

```
myMeans <- ddply(myData[,c("Hour", "IT_solar_generation")], "Hour", numcolwise(mean))
```

The resulting frame will have one column called Time which will give you the hour, and another with the means at each hour.

NOW, on another side but important note, when you ask a question you should be providing information on the attempts you've made so far to answer the question. This isn't a help desk.

Comment: Okay, I will take care from now onwards, Thank You !!

Comment: No worry, I hope you enjoy the community! If you're happy with my response please mark this as the answer :)

Comment: I should clarify my comment about 'Help Desk' as well! We're certainly here to help, but we're not a help desk in the sense that we're your first port of call. Hopefully if you've come here to ask a question you've already done some research, given it a crack and can then report the research and attempts you've made in the question. I appreciate that some times you are just completely stumped though, and that's okay too!

Comment: Yeah, I got it and I made several attempts to, but right now I am not used to the way of this community, so I will try to learn from you guys. Well, thanks for your suggestions.